# Use T4 .tt templates with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, visual-studio-2013, t4

Searching around the web I find many issues from 2007 upwards to about 2010 with issues around the T4 engine locking assemblies. This issue is caused as such:

1. Create .tt T4 template
2. Reflect on certain assembly within same solution, using it to generate code
3. T4 generates code on ctrl+s
4. T4 now has reflected assembly locked
5. Building the solution will fail, since the resulting .dll file of the reflected assembly is now locked and Visual Studio can't release it.

Solutions by Oleg Sych (T4 lead developer) are

- Use EnvDTE (api to talk to Visual Studio)
- FxCop's Introspection (custom .NET reflection API)

Both solutions are suboptimal for my usecase. We already have much reflection code on our contracts. Furthermore, reflection as an API is hard enough, let alone requiring developers to understand a *second* API to reason about code structure.

Is there a way to still utilize our use-case? This use-case being:

- Use T4
- Reflect on assembly in same project as T4 lives
- Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 2):

You can load your assemblies for reflection in a new `AppDomain` which shadow copies the binaries from their original locations.

[Shadow Copying Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx)

Apparently if you use the [T4 Assembly Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx), the shadow copying is [handled for you starting with Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2010/12/11/vs2010-sp1-t4-no-longer-locks-assemblies-in-memory.aspx).

Comment: Indeed, this is what I have done. No problem with dll files being blocked. However, reflection + T4 could be devil because if you have an error in C#, reflection won't work, new code will not be generated to fix that error. Be careful.